# How to use touch events in prototype js?

Tags: javascript, events, touch, prototype

I know that prototype isn't supported anymore but it's not that old that it shouldn't cover some touch events, right? Still I didn't find a thing about it...

I just want that a double click function works on mobile devices. So how to transform this:

```
<selector>.observe('dblclick', function(ev) {
   ...
}.bind(this));
```

into a touch event function or better bind the double click and the touch event in one function?

Comment: Prototype is supported http://prototypejs.org/2014/04/18/prototype-1-7-2/ and you might find some answers in this Pull Request https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/pull/106 - If that doesnt solve your problem please post an issue in the repo https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/issues?state=open

Comment: Thx! Meanwhile I found a solution. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
element.observe('touchstart', function (ev) {
  ...
}
```

is the solution.